# SQL Select Statement for text within a field that includes double and or single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do the following query in SQL Server Manager:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[content]
where content_html like %<images><img src='/' alt=''></img></images>%'
```

I need to search for that exact string that exists in numerous content items and is breaking an XML feed I am creating.

```
<images><img src='/' alt=''></img></images>
```

The problem here are the single quotes while performing the query.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please don't change question like you did(title and body) because you invalidated posted correct answers. If you need further help consider asking new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to search for `'` you need to double it (`''` inside `'...'` is treated as single `'`):

```
CREATE TABLE #content(content_html VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #content(content_html)
VALUES ('<images><img src=''/'' alt=''''></img></images>')

SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM #content
where content_html like '%<images>%<img src=''/'' alt=''''></img>%</images>%'
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/412874)**</kbd>

Output:

```
<images><img src='/' alt=''></img></images>
```

Comment: It doesn't return any results on the select query. It doesn't crash but it seems it doesn't match anything within the data even though It's displayed exactly like this in the data: <images><img src='/' alt=''></img></images>

Comment: @MathieuBeausoleil Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data where it doesn't work

Comment: I think the problem is that the data actually has spaces in it like follows: '<images>      <img src='/' alt=''>      </img>    </images>' -- there are different amounts of spaces in between each tag. This content is generated by a CMS

Comment: @MathieuBeausoleil How about `where content_html like '%<images>%<img src=''/'' alt=''''></img>%</images>%'`?

Comment: You nailed it on the head! Thanks so much!

Comment: Ok so the select query works: SELECT *
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[content]
where content_html like '%<images>%<img src=''/'' alt=''''>%</img>%</images>%'

Comment: But the update query does not -- any ideas? UPDATE [myDB].[dbo].[content]
SET content_html=REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), content_html),'%<images>%<img src=''/'' alt=''''>%</img>%</images>%','<images></images>')

Comment: @Mat Quick **[POC](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/412933)** to handle more cases you need to ask new question and preapre solid input sample

Answer (score 2):

You need to add wrap `single quotes` with `single quotes`. Try this

```
declare @var varchar(4000) = '<images><img src=''/'' alt=''''></img></images>'

SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[content]
where content_html like '%'+var+'%'
```

Also using `TOP` without `Order by` does not guarantee same `TOP 100` result everytime

Answer (score 0):

use escape characters

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[content] where content_html like ''%%''

should work